# Customizing angularjs bootstrap calendar

Tags: css, angularjs, calendar

I am using angular bootstrap calendar for my application.I am getting events from database and displaying on calendar.Now after clicking on any cell it opens a popup modal for adding events.But what i am trying to do is i have placed a glyphicon "+" for every cell.After clicking on "+" i want to call modal popup for adding events.Now after clicking on cell the modal is displayed.

Here is my html

```
    <mwl-calendar
    events="events"
    view="calendarView"
    current-day="viewDate"
    view-title="calendarTitle"
    custom-template-urls="{calendarMonthCell: 'customMonthCell.html'}"
    ng-model="eventSources"
    cell-is-open="cellIsOpen"
    day-view-start="06:00"
    day-view-end="22:59"
    day-view-split="30"
    cell-modifier="modifyCell(calendarCell)"
    cell-auto-open-disabled="true"
    on-timespan-click="timespanClicked(calendarDate)">
    </mwl-calendar>
```

Here is the css where i am adding "+" for every cell.

angular-bootstrap-calendar.css

```
    .cal-cell:hover:before{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: "\f055";
    float:right;
```

}

Here is the controller.js

```
    $scope.timespanClicked = function(notifyDate) {
    $scope.notifyDate = notifyDate;
    UserProfileService.getAllUsers().then(function(response2){
        $scope.users = response2.data;
    }); 
    $(".addnotify").modal("show");
    };
```

[image: Image for calendar]

As you can see on date 17th there is a small + icon at right top.After clicking the + i need to display the modal popup.I have used hover.Therefore after hovering on particular cell + appears.